# Error 1:17 when starting R, f(interactive()){

Tags: r

I've recently started using R. Each time I start R (either in the terminal or in RStudio) I get the following error,

```
    Error: 1:17: unexpected '{'
    1: f(interactive()){`
```

Furthermore this error prevents me from being able to install any packages as any attempt to do so returns,

```
    Execution halted
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
    Error: 1:17: unexpected '{'
    1: f(interactive()){
```

I've tried to google the error but I've not found any results relating to this problem. I've tried reinstalling R but the problem persists.

I'm using Linux Mint 17.2.

This is what I did to install R

```
    sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And I added the line

```
    deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/
```

Then,

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
    sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Problem solved! Can you post it as an answer to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a .Rprofile file? It looks like somebody accidentally changed `if(interactive()){` to `f(interactive()){`